# Second root which redirects to users profile page when logged in without using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

The problem I'm currently having is setting up the root page to redirect to the logged in users profile page. My root page is a simple landing page with links to login or sign up. I don't want that page to be accessible once logged in because its fairly pointless to go there.

Here is my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/eugenetriguba/cortex/tree/0cc3453c6f183b2645a29c8c417c82b5a8dc5cce) for this project if you need more context or if I didn't provide something you would need.

What I was going to try to do is add a `before_action` to the `SessionsController`

```
before_action :user_authenticated, only: [:new]

def user_authenticated
  @user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
  if logged_in?
    redirect_to @user
  end
end
```

And a second root above the first one in the `routes.rb` file.

```
root to: 'sessions#new'
```

[image: Error]

I can't exactly figure out what's wrong with that line and if I remove it, I just get another error. I'm assuming something in that line doesn't have a value or it doesn't know about something. I feel like this should be a trivial problem, but I keep getting hung up on it.

Here is how my sessions_controller.rb & routes.rb files are currently without those snippets of code

```
# sessions_controller.rb
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in @user
      params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(@user) : forget(@user)
      redirect_to @user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out if logged_in?
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end

# routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root   'static_pages#home'
  get    '/signup',   to: 'users#new'
  post   '/signup',   to: 'users#create'
  get    '/login',    to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',    to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',   to: 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users
end
```

It seems like you can use constraints also, but I couldn't get it to work. There seems to be tons of answers when using Devise, but I feel it would be kinda odd to add in Devise just to redirect back to their profile.

This is a stackoverflow answer I looked at that could be relevant, but didn't have much luck with it.

[Specify a different root path for logged in users without using Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37981511/specify-a-different-root-path-for-logged-in-users-without-using-devise)

Comment: Are you following any tutorial?

Comment: @Hizqeel I've went through a couple Rails books but never actually made something on my own. Most of the login code on here follows the Ruby on Rails tutorial book by Michael hartl.

Comment: What i am getting is that.. You don't want not to see and access the landing page(with links login and signup) after login but only the user profile page
for that try in `static_pages_controller.rb`  **`def home if logged_in? redirect_to current_user end end`**

Comment: @Hizqeel Ah that worked perfectly. I tried that but for some reason, I tried to use redirect_to [at symbol]user, not current_user, and it would throw an error. Such a simple fix, sorry about that. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that ... I have written an answer for that please mark it as accepted so that it will help others in future..! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `static_pages_controller.rb` file just add:

```
def home 
 if logged_in? 
  redirect_to current_user 
 end 
end
```